# Laowa 7,5 mm F2 Lightweight Micro 4/3 vs. Laowa 7,5 mm F2 Standard Micro 4/3

Tags: lens-design, wide-angle

I am interested in buying a wide-angle lens. 
The Laowa 7.5mm F2 Micro 4/3 seems to be the best option for my purpose.
I have found it in an online shop and was wondering why the lightweight version (for drones) is cheaper than the regular one. A friend of mine advised me not to buy the lightweight version since he assumes that the lenses of the lightweight version are made from some plastic glass mixture (which reduces the life time, in his opinion).
Does anybody know what exactly the difference (in terms of materials used) between these two lenses is?
I have already contacted the importer for my country (Brenner Import und Handels GmbH ) but they have not answered so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs in my online camera shop, the standard version is 170g while the "light" version is 150g. Replacing glass by plastic would save a lot more. IMHO they just put some lighter material (plastic or light alloy) here and there.

And IMHO your friend talks utter nonsense, because changing the lens material changes everything. The refractive index would be different, as would its variation with wavelength, so you would have to design a completely different lens around that different material.

Comment: So you do not think that the light version has a reduced lifetime?

Comment: No, IMHO the "weak" point is the bayonet mount, but even on the light version is a metal one. But unless you are pro and this is you usual lens it will outlive you (or at least be obsolete before it fails).